# How can I turn off notice suppression in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

Zend is automatically suppressing notices, how can I change this application wide to halt execution when a notice occurs?

For instance, an undefined variable or missing parameter (which causes an undefined variable) will show a notice in the error log. If this notice occurs in a method that writes to a database, no data will be written and no error will be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the PHP error settings in `application/configs/application.ini`. The typical setup is this:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

which means hide errors in production mode but show in development.

Comment: Errors are displayed fine, notices are not. I am also in dev mode.

Comment: In that case check the error_reporting level in your php.ini. ZF does not change this by default.

Comment: My error_reporting level in my php.ini is fine. Something like a missing parameter in a method call or an undefined variable is not triggering anything. I've had the guys at #php on freenode go over the ini and it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are in "development" mode not "production".

Check `index.php` in your `public` folder:

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV',(getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'): 'production'));
```

just change `production` to `development` as this will lead to reading the configuration from the development section of `application/configs/application.ini`

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

Comment: Errors are displayed fine, notices are not. I am also in dev mode.

Comment: hmmmm weird!! Have u tried putting `error_reporting(-1);` in `index.php` ?

Comment: error_reporting(0); in the very begining of index.php worked for me.